# how post data in apex code

Tags: apex

I have data in json want to send it to server in json format with http request.
    I am getting this error

```
{ "code": "invalid_response", "description": "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'", "success": false }
```

can any one help me please?

code is

```
    string str2='{"_key":"a8b2ed3b33403dcaf13c0796f26a82ead1e4","X845HyzVts":[[],["","","","","",""]]}';

      string result= API_Request('https://ezqcp.fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/surveys/'+54305+'/responses/','POST',str2);


public String API_Request(String url, String method, String body)
    {


     String apiKey = 'gKnD34Bc343bPffC3h2qGK';
     String pwd = 'ccccccccc014';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res;
        try{
            req.setEndPoint(url);
            req.setTimeout(20000);
            req.setMethod(method);
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(apiKey + ':' + pwd);
            String authorizationHeader = 'Basic '+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Content-Length','31999'); 
            if (method=='POST')
            {
                req.setBody(body);
            }
            res = http.send(req);
            String str1= res.getBody();
           // system.debug(str1);
             return str1;
             }catch(Exception e){    
                        return e;
                         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the JSON is being sent to the server but is not the structure expected at your endpoint.

You are sending key "X845HyzVts" with values of a list, containing two lists. First list empty and second list containing five blank strings.

The error message from the server sounds like it is not expecting one of those lists, it's expecting a value "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

edit---

Have you any documentation from fluidsurveys as to what format the data should be provided in? Currently you are providing this:

```
{
   "_key":"a8b2ed3b33403dcaf13c0796f26a82ead1e4",
   "X845HyzVts":[
      [

      ],
      [
         "",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         ""
      ]
   ]
}
```

and you are getting an error message that the argument should be a string or number, not a list. The JSON you are sending contains three lists and so it suggests that one or more of these is incorrect. Maybe it would rather have something like this:

```
{
   "_key":"a8b2ed3b33403dcaf13c0796f26a82ead1e4",
   "X845HyzVts":"someValue"
}
```

or this:

```
{
   "_key":"a8b2ed3b33403dcaf13c0796f26a82ead1e4",
   ["X845HyzVts":"someValue"]
}
```

but ultimately it's very tricky to guess the format of data expected by a server. Try reading the API documentation for the service you are using - this is available here http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/api/surveys.html

Comment: Hi Doug B, str2='{"_key":"a8b2ed3b33403dcaf13c0796f26a82ead1e4","X845HyzVts":[[0,1,2,3,4,5],["","","","","",""]]}'; still error